# Add another string to the regex !^/js/

Tags: regex, .htaccess

This regex `!^/js/` excludes `js`, how can I add the word `blog` in there?

Context: Using in htaccess IE `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/`

Comment: `|` matches one of several alternatives; you can look it up in a regex reference

Comment: @Ryan Stackoverflow is a much better reference than official docs, else it wouldn't exist. The first part of your answer was enough.

Comment: I said “a regex reference”, not “official docs”, and it was just a supplement to the answer of `|`. You can look up `|` in https://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html and find https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html; you can’t look up “how can I add the word `blog`” in such a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is totally unclear, if you want to match the path `/blog/js`:

`!^/blog/js/`

If you want to match `js` or `blog`:

`!^/(blog|js)/`

Comment: Yep it's the latter. Thanks